# Slider Updates on Iphone dont work

Tags: javascript, iphone

Does anyone have an idea why the values on the right side don't update on an Iphone?
I am confused. It works (relatively) fine on android and on desktop browsers so far.

http://jenseickhoff.de/slider/rechner.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay - I think it is this part:

```
$(document).on("mousedown keydown", function(){ 
            invl = setInterval(function(){refresh()},10);
    });
```

It looks like you need to add the iOS touch events too, i.e. **touchstart**

```
$(document).on("mousedown keydown touchstart", function(){ 
                invl = setInterval(function(){refresh()},10);
        });
```

I think this will fix your issue, lots more on touch events here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Comment: You were right. It was the missing touchstart. Not at that exact point because that was the function for non-mobile devices but the other part just said *taphold keydown* so I added *touchstart* too and that did the magic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Might be because you are multiplying strings with numbers and maybe Safari on the iPad has a stricter JS engine?

Thats all I could think of, e.g. this line:

```
$("#co2emission").html(toLocalFormat($("#leistung").html()*$('#slider-vertical').val()*0.00055/0.9, true));
```

Takes an html string and multiplies it by a number.
Thats all I can think of right now :)

Comment: I agree with this answer. Try parseInt(elem.html(), 10);

Comment: That does not seem to be the reason: I took out all but    $("#leistung").html($('#slider-vertical2').val()); and it still won't work.